# Combinations for a collection which should hold x items, where there are y types and z of each type

Tags: combinatorics

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522748/this-one-may-be-a-doozy-all-possible-card-combinations-of-a-deck-of-cards), but I plan on writing a more clear question, using smaller numbers for examples, and I want to understand how to approach the problem rather than having an answer for one case.

#### Example

Let's say that you have three different types of items, for simplicity sake let's call the them `a b c`. You have three of each type. And you want to create a collection holding four items in total. So you have `aaabbbccc` and you should **pick 4** of them.

9 nCr 4 is not the correct answer since it doesn't matter **which** a, which b or which c you pick. All that matters is **how many**. The number of possible combinations is 12, the possible combinations are: aaab, aaac, aabb, aabc, aacc, abbb, abbc, abcc, accc, bbbc, bbcc, bccc.

#### My current approach

Since I am a programmer, I wrote a method in Java for determining this. It uses recursion to compute the correct number. So if you know programming, here is what I have done:

```
public int deckCombos(int cardsInDeck, int numCardTypes, int numOfEachType) {
    if (cardsInDeck < 0)
        return 0;
    if (cardsInDeck == 1)
        return numCardTypes;
    if (numCardTypes == 1)
        return numOfEachType >= cardsInDeck ? 1 : 0;
    
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfEachType; i++) {
        result += deckCombos(cardsInDeck - i, numCardTypes - 1, numOfEachType);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem of this approach is that when dealing with bigger numbers it gets slower, because of all the recursion.

#### Other attempts at solving the general problem

There has to be a lot of combinatorics here. I figured that for the example above, there are 9 items in total and so there are 9! ways of ordering them. Since there are 3 of each type we can divide by 3! three times.

But then we should also pick 4 of them, but when dividing by 4! (because the order of the first four elements doesn't matter) and 5! (because the order of the last 5 elements doesn't matter).

The result then becomes 7/12 which is obviously wrong since 0.58333 combinations just doesn't make sense. I understand this is because when dividing by both 3! and 5!, some combinations are removed twice.

## The question

How can I calculate mathematically (or in a faster programmatically way) the number of combinations when wanting to choose x items in total when having y types of items and z items of each type?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's a bit too long for a comment. Besides, maybe bumping on the front page helps you or this gives someone more competent an idea.

You actually need [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) with the constraints: maximal number that can be used is $z$ and the number of the summands should be at most $y$.

In your example above, the corresponding sums are

\begin{align*}
x = 4 &= 3+1+0 = 3+0+1 = 2+2+0 = 2+1+1 = 2+0+2 = 1+3+0 \\
&= 1+2+1 = 1+1+2 = 1+0+3 = 0+3+1 = 0+2+2 = 0+1+3.
\end{align*}

So, $3$ summands ($y = 3$, corresponding to "a", "b", and "c"), all less than or equal to $3$ (because you have $z = 3$ of each) and the sum is $x=4$.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough combinatorics to tackle this. Try to start from the Wikipedia link above (especially a generating function and how to apply restrictions to it), and see if somebody has done something similar enough.